# SQL selecting multiple columns and MAX from one of the columns, only one row to be returned

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, max

I need to select multiple columns from a table, together with a max value from one of the columns
The result must be only that one row where the max value is in.
Here's a simplified version of my table (sorry, don't know how to insert spaces)

```
╔═════════╦══════════╦═══════════╗
║ CARMAKE ║ CARMODEL ║ CARWEIGHT ║
╠═════════╬══════════╬═══════════╣
║ A       ║ B        ║      1000 ║
║ C       ║ D        ║       900 ║
╚═════════╩══════════╩═══════════╝
```

The desired result would be

```
╔═════════╦══════════╦═══════════╗
║ CARMAKE ║ CARMODEL ║ CARWEIGHT ║
╠═════════╬══════════╬═══════════╣
║ A       ║ B        ║      1000 ║
╚═════════╩══════════╩═══════════╝
```

But when I use

```
SELECT carmake, carmodel, MAX(carweight)
FROM   car
GROUP  BY carmake, carmodel
```

It will show the max of each make etc. instead of only the row with the absolute max. How can I do that?

Comment: wow, kudos for that edit @JW

Answer (score 4):

You can use subquery which gets the maximum value of the `carweight` table and equate it to the outer query's `carweight`.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
WHERE   carweight = (SELECT MAX(carweight) FROM tableName)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad8bd/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔═════════╦══════════╦═══════════╗
║ CARMAKE ║ CARMODEL ║ CARWEIGHT ║
╠═════════╬══════════╬═══════════╣
║ A       ║ B        ║      1000 ║
╚═════════╩══════════╩═══════════╝
```

The advantage of this is it supports ties, in which they have the same `carweight` and happens to be the maximum value.

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*with tie*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7c348/1)

Comment: by the way, What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: I'm using microsoft acces to do this